# Inserting rows additional to requirements

Tags: vba, excel

I've compiled a macro which uses an input box to allow the user to insert a specified number of rows in multiple places on three different sheets within the same workbook. It then subsequently populates these new rows with the appropriate data using autofill based on an example first row.

It does all of the above correctly. However, it also inserts the user specified number of rows into the 'Front Sheet' which is always the activesheet when the macro is run. It is not one of the destinations I specify to insert the rows.

From user testing the unwanted rows are not inserted in a consistent place but appear in different places within the sheet, seemingly varying with the number specified in the input box. It doesn't populate these excess rows as it does the desired ones.

```
Sub AddPlots()
    Dim j As Integer, r As Range,

    'Set Number of Rows to be added
    j = InputBox("How many open market units does the development have?")

    ' Add Rows On Master Appraisal
    With Worksheets("Master Appraisal")
        Set r = Range("FirstPlot")
        Do
            Range(r.Offset(1, 0), r.Offset(j - 1, 0)).EntireRow.Insert
            Set r = Cells(r.Row + j + 1, 1)
            If r.Offset(1, 0) = "" Then Exit Do
        Loop
    End With

'Add Rows On Cashflow
    With Worksheets("Cashflow")
        Set r = Range("FirstPlot2")
        Do
            Range(r.Offset(1, 0), r.Offset(j - 1, 0)).EntireRow.Insert
            Set r = Cells(r.Row + j + 1, 1)
            If r.Offset(1, 0) = "" Then Exit Do
        Loop
    End With

'Add Rows On Fees (NHBC section)

    With Worksheets("Fees etc")
        Set r = Range("FirstPlot3")
        Do
            Range(r.Offset(1, 0), r.Offset(j - 1, 0)).EntireRow.Insert
            Set r = Cells(r.Row + j + 1, 1)
            If r.Offset(1, 0) = "" Then Exit Do
        Loop
    End With

'Add Rows On Fees (Marketing section)
    With Worksheets("Fees etc")
        Set r = Range("FirstPlot4")
        Do
            Range(r.Offset(1, 0), r.Offset(j - 1, 0)).EntireRow.Insert
            Set r = Cells(r.Row + j + 1, 1)
            If r.Offset(1, 0) = "" Then Exit Do
        Loop
    End With

'Populate New Rows with Data
    Worksheets("Cashflow").Range("Topline2").AutoFill
    Destination:=Range("Topline2").Resize(j), Type:=xlFillDefault
    Worksheets("Master Appraisal").Range("Topline").AutoFill 
    Destination:=Range("Topline").Resize(j), Type:=xlFillDefault
    Worksheets("Fees etc").Range("Topline3").AutoFill
    Destination:=Range("Topline3").Resize(j), Type:=xlFillDefault
    Worksheets("Fees etc").Range("Topline4").AutoFill
    Destination:=Range("Topline4").Resize(j), Type:=xlFillDefault

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are using a `WITH....END WITH` code block any ranges that you want to reference the correct worksheet must start with a period (`.`) otherwise it will reference the active sheet.

So `Range(r.Offset(1, 0), r.Offset(j - 1, 0)).EntireRow.Insert` references the active sheet, while `.Range(r.Offset(1, 0), r.Offset(j - 1, 0)).EntireRow.Insert` references the sheet used in your `WITH` statement.

Edit:
Also `Cells(r.Row + j + 1, 1)` should be `.Cells(r.Row + j + 1, 1)` - these lines will update your `r` reference from the sheet used in the named range `FirstPlot` to look at the active sheet rather than the `WITH` sheet.

Comment: Thanks very much! I thought it was probably something simple - I really appreciate you taking the time to explain it to me so clearly.